# "NullReferenceException was Unhandled"

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a project here in my ojt. vb2010 form. I am getting this error:

> "NullReferenceException was Unhandled"

Why do I get it?

this is my code;

```
Private Sub RefreshData()
    If Not con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then

        con.Open()
    End If

    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT ID as [ID], " & _
                                         "fname as [NAME], lname" & _
                                      "FROM asdf ORDER by ID", con)

    da.Fill(ds.Tables("asdf"))****  this part is where i get the error*****
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Most likely, `ds` has not been instantiated by the time you try to access its `Tables` collection. Where is `ds` even declared?

Comment: can you give some hint on how to fix this problem?  im just a newbie in vb. and this is my first project.

Answer (score 1):

Error says what it means,

Put a null check

```
if(ds != null && ds.Tables("asdf") != null)  then
.... ' put da.Fill here
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

"[NullReferenceExeption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception.aspx) was Unhandled" error indicates that you are trying to use a null object in the code. Do a `null check` like:-

```
if(con != null) then
      'your code...
end if


if(ds != null && ds.Tables("asdf") != null) then
    'your code...
end if
```

Comment: i tried your codes sir but i ger a ""Identifier Expected"" on the "=" sign.

Comment: i used it but i get the ""expression expected"" error on the "&&" sign.  yes i'm using vb2010. i'm just a newbie in vb. this is just my first application.

Comment: simply write `And` in place of `&&` operator. The above answer only depicts the logic, not syntax. For and VB uses `And`.

Comment: i already did that but i got this error "Operator '<>' is not defined for types 'System.Data.DataTable' and 'Boolean?'"

Comment: Ok, do like this `If ds IsNot Nothing And ds.Tables("asdf") IsNot Nothing Then 'your code`.

Comment: i tried it but it looks that DataSet is null. now, my question is how can i give a value to the dataset?